# Simple Dropdownlist from a simple model with MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a simple Model:

```
public partial class Entidade
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    public virtual Pais Pais { get; set; }
}
```

related with the Pais model:

```
public partial class Pais
{
    public Pais()
    {
        this.Entidades = new HashSet<Entidade>();
    }

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Entidade> Entidades { get; set; }
}
```

and I need to build a simple dropdown list of the Pais's to create a new Entidade:

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Pais, "Pais")
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Pais, ViewBag.Paises as SelectList)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Pais)
</div>
```

from the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(Entidade entidade)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entidades.Add(entidade);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    ViewBag.Paises = new SelectList(db.Paises, "Id", "Nome");

    return View(entidade);
}
```

But I get the error:

```
There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'Pais'.
```

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, thanks I have added the Controller's code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this:

Pais.cs

```
public Pais()
        {
            Entidades = new HashSet<Entidade>();
        }

        [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Entidade> Entidades { get; set; }
```

Entidade.cs

```
public class Entidade
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Pais")]
        public int PaisId { get; set; }
        public virtual Pais Pais { get; set; }
    }
```

EntidateController.cs

```
//GET: /Entidade/Create
 public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.PaisId = new SelectList(db.Paises, "Id", "Nome");
        return View();
    }

// POST: /Entidade/Create
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(Entidade entidade)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entidades.Add(entidade);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    ViewBag.PaisId = new SelectList(db.Paises, "Id", "Nome", entidade.PaisId);
    return View(entidade);
}
```

Entidate Create.cshtml

```
@Html.DropDownList("PaisId", String.Empty)
```

Comment: Hi thanks, but why do you need the "[Bind(Include="Id,Nome,PaisId")]" in the create action?

Comment: [Bind(Include="")] is optional as I just used auto generated code. Basically Include / Exclude is useful when you want to bind only specific properties to the model and exclude others. More info can be found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19490121/need-guide-line-for-mvc-action-method-with-bind-attribute

Comment: Hi thanks, I was able to solve the problem based on your solution, with just two things, ViewBag.PaisId instead of ViewBag.PaisSelectList to map the form submit field and @Html.DropDownList("PaisId") in the View. Please change your response so I can set it has correct ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are creating adrop down for a Pais entity not for it's Id, so:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Pais.Id, ViewBag.Paises as SelectList)
```

But this will end up in a NullReferenceException if you aren't setting the model Pais property to an instance.

Addtitional tip: if you can try avoid using ViewBag or ViewData. In this sitiation you can create a EntidadeViewModel class even derived from Entidade and this can have a property of type IEnumerable. In this way your code will be more readable and consistent.

Comment: I get the error: There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'Pais.Id'.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
ViewBag.Paises = db.Paises.ToList();

@Html.DropDownList("Id",new SelectList(ViewBag.Paises,"Id","Nome"))
```