# An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker error when trying to save changes to multiple types of entities

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a controller action where I am attempting to both create a new object in the database, of type `FantasyTeam`, and also modify an existing object, of type User. However, when the action is called I am receiving a `System.InvalidOperationException` exception, with the explanation of:

> An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of
>   IEntityChangeTracker.

My code is below.

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include="ID,FantasyTeamName")] FantasyTeam fantasyteam)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var CurrentUser = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
            fantasyteam.OwnerID = CurrentUser.Id;
            CurrentUser.HasTeam = true;

            db.FantasyTeams.Add(fantasyteam);
            db.Entry(CurrentUser).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Dashboard", "Application");
        }

        return View(fantasyteam);
    }
```

The Controller Action takes the new `FantasyTeam` object as a parameter from the View where the team details are selected by user. I then find the currently logged in user and set the `OwnerID` of the team to match the `UserID` of the owner, *as my Foreign Key*. I then go to add the new `FantasyTeam` to the database and also modify the User record in the database, changing the Boolean `HasTeam` to `true`. **The adding of the new team works fine on its own... I have been getting the exception once I tried to modify the User object as well.**

I have searched on StackOverflow for this exception, and have found many related issues, but I couldn't find a way to apply the other resolutions to my problem. In some cases the issue was that the developers were using two separate data contexts when they should have just been using one, but I don't think that would apply to me here.

Could someone offer insight as to what might be going wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: Make sure `db` and the internal context used by `UserManager` are (using) the same context.

Comment: That is exactly what it was - I didn't realize that the UserManager was using a different context than the one the "db" item was using. Thanks!

Comment: Any chance someone could point me to an article that explains the `([Bind(Include="ID,FantasyTeamName")] FantasyTeam fantasyteam)` syntax? I've not seen it before but assume it's something to do with custom binding.

Comment: It's about halfway down the page in this tutorial: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/examining-the-edit-methods-and-edit-view

Comment: Always worrying when I'm told to look at a **getting started** tutorial :) Thanks for that, I'll take a look.

Comment: Oh ffs, I know what that is now, lol. My mind is forgetting too many things :)

Comment: @webnoob, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/19490684

Comment: @haim770 Yeah, got it thanks. As soon as I read the asp.net article, I remembered what they were. Sigh. Thanks for the reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Linq to SQL DataContext Lifetime Management](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2008/Feb/05/Linq-to-SQL-DataContext-Lifetime-Management) the main causality of the problem comes from the below reason.

Linq to SQL uses a `DataContext` to manage it's access to the database as well as tracking changes made to entities retrieved from the database. Linq to SQL has a persistent approach to managing its 'connection' to the database via this data context and it basically assumes that you use a single `DataContext` to make all of your data related access. This doesn't mean that it makes persistent connections to the database, but means that the `DataContext` instance maintains state about active result sets, *which is especially important if change tracking is on which is the default.*

Answer (score 0):

The comment posted by haim770 was the answer - I didn't realize that the UserManager object was using a different context than the db object was using. Once I changed the UserManager object to use the same context as db, my code works as intended.