# What is the use of "BIND" in mvc ActionResult method parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

In mvc-5 application I created a class named Album.

I wanted to make the CRUID options easy and then created: MVC5 Controller with views using Entity Framework.

After I completed this dialog:

[image]

It created a class in model directory and some files in views and controllers directory.

in controllers directory it created a controller which contains this section of code in which there is a line of code I dont know what is it:

```
 // GET: Albums/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.ArtistId = new SelectList(db.Artists, "ArtistId", "ArtistName");
        ViewBag.GenreId = new SelectList(db.Genres, "GenreId", "Name");
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Albums/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "AlbumId,GenreId,ArtistId,Title,Price,AlbumArtUrl")] Album album)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Albums.Add(album);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.ArtistId = new SelectList(db.Artists, "ArtistId", "ArtistName", album.ArtistId);
        ViewBag.GenreId = new SelectList(db.Genres, "GenreId", "Name", album.GenreId);
        return View(album);
    }
```

What is the meaning of this line:

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "AlbumId,GenreId,ArtistId,Title,Price,AlbumArtUrl")] Album album)
```

Please explain deeply I dont understand the use of Bind and Include

Thanks.

Comment: If you posting back all properties of your model, then the `Include` property of `BindAttribute` is pointless. But you should always use a view model anyway so that you never have to use `[Bind(Include="...")]`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19490121/need-guide-line-for-mvc-action-method-with-bind-attribute

Check this

Comment: @StephenMuecke Would you please explain your comment more clearly and in a simpler state.

Comment: Which bit are you not understanding?